# Is it possible to handle a value as either an xml attribute or element?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xjc, hl7

I'm implementing some of the IHE ITI HL7 profiles and there is available schema from which I've generated JaxB classes. Recently I discovered there are some differences between different versions of the schema. In particular, some XML elements are now XML attributes.

Previously the typeCode attribute was mapped to an XML element, see example below:

```
 <acknowledgement>
    <typeCode code="AE"/>
</acknowledgement>
```

Now the typecode attribute is mapped to an XML attribute, see example below:

```
<acknowledgement typeCode="AE"/>
```

Is there any way I can have a class using whatever annotations or other possibilities that could handle a message with a typecode that comes in either of these forms? Even better, is there a way to have the XJC generator do it for me automatically, perhaps with some kind of binding?

Currently it's just a field with an @XmlAttribute annotation.

Comment: Is there any reason not to just map both and have a helper method that grabs whatever isn't null?

Comment: I suppose I might have to do that. I would really like to find a solution that I could apply generally via the code generation because there's, oh, about 1500 classes. Now, I could probably wittle it down to just the use cases I'm aware of, but that's a little iffy.

Comment: I'd rather generate different JAXB classes for each specific XSD version. This introduces some redundacies, but you're on the safe side...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're willing to get your hands a little dirty, you might be able accomplish this quite nicely using an XJC plugin.  XJC has a plugin facility which allows you to get access to the model classes as they are being built using the [Sun Codemodel API](http://codemodel.java.net/nonav/apidocs/com/sun/codemodel/package-summary.html).  Takes a little bit of wrangling to get started with, but once you figure out the basics, it's not too hard to do all sorts of useful things during JAXB model generation.  There's a good tutorial [here](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/kohsuke/archive/2005/06/writing_a_plugi.html).

Now, assuming you have some configuration which tells you which elements are now attributes, i *think* you could modify the model class so that it looks something like:

```
public class MyModel
{
  // this part is automatically generated by xjc
  @XmlAttribute
  public String foo;

  // you add this with your custom xjc plugin
  @XmlElement(name="foo")
  public String getFooElement() { return foo; }
  public void setFooElement(String newFoo) { foo = newFoo; }
}
```

I haven't actually tested out this theory, but it should be pretty easy to manually modify your model classes to see if the general idea works.

Comment: That looks promising as far as the generation goes. As your example shows, this a valid way of handling this situation. At the very worst, I can edit the code or the schema if I can't get the XJC generation quite right. Thanks.